# Difficulty remapping the Super-Key

Tags: keymap, keyboard-layout

Have been trying to change keymaps.  Specifically, making the Super-Key to be remapped as the Meta-Key (Alt-Key).

This is what I have originally

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant dvorak
xmodmap -pke | grep "Control\|Alt\|Meta\|Hyper\|Super"

keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode 205 = NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 207 = NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L
```

---

```
xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

These are the changes I do with `xmodmap`.  What I want is to
swap the `Meta-Key` and `Control-Key` (making the `Control-Key` the key
closest to the `Space-Key`).  Next and to the left have the `Meta-Key`,
followed by the `Hyper-Key`.

Then the placements would be

Super-Key to use Caps_Lock
(Hyper | Meta | Control | Space)

```
clear lock
clear mod3

!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!! Set Alt-Key (Meta-Key) to position of Super-Key

clear mod4

keycode 133 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 134 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R

add mod4 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_R Meta_R

!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!! Set Hyper-Key to position of Ctrl-Key

clear mod1

keycode 37 = Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol
keycode 105 = Hyper_R NoSymbol Hyper_R NoSymbol

add mod1 = Hyper_L Hyper_R

!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!! Set Ctrl-Key to position of Alt-Key (Meta-Key) 

clear control

keycode 64 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L NoSymbol
keycode 108 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R NoSymbol

add control = Control_L Control_R 

!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!! Set Super-Key to position of Caps-Lock

clear mod2

keycode 66 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R NoSymbol
keycode 207 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol

add mod2 = Super_L Super_R
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the "difficulty" is, so this seems unanswerable.  I suggest using `xev -event keyboard` and providing details.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Emacs.  I'll migrate it.